# Set default public variable at the first time and increase it in the next time?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I tried to write VBA script in outlook to increase row of cells in excel. But I cannot set default value for this variable (I use public variable and row of cell should be started from "2").

How can I use script VBA in outlook to set second row of cell ( cell(2,1) =1) in excel at the first time, and increase row of cell for the next time

Here is my code in outlook. and when I run it, It said that "Invalid outside procedure"

```
Public count As Integer: count = 2

Sub test()

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Check file open or not, and open it if it isn't opened
    If (IsWorkBookOpen("D:\Book1.xlsx") = True) Then
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
    Else
        Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Book1.xlsx")
    End If

    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Process excel file
    xlSheet.Cells(count, 1) = 1
    count = count + 1

End Sub

Function IsWorkBookOpen(FileName As String) 'function to check excel file is open or not
    Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    ErrNo = Err
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case ErrNo
    Case 0:    IsWorkBookOpen = False
    Case 70:   IsWorkBookOpen = True
    Case Else: Error ErrNo
    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA you can not assign value to a non-constant outside of a subroutine.

`Public count As Integer: count = 2`

You can just initialize your public variable using the `Workbook_Open()` event.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    counter = 2
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can use `GetSettings` and `SaveSetting`Reference: [MSDN GetSetting Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb0c3wb9(v=vs.90).aspx)

[image]

Comment: Yes, I regconized about this and I don't know how to solve it. If I do like you, for each time when I run macro, It will never increase row of cell which cell is started from row 2

Comment: Now, for each time when I run macro, i face a problem which I tried to avoid this problem at first time: Excel file always reopen for each time when I run macro. Do you have another way

Comment: I don't have time to explain but see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

use `Static` variables to preserve their value between different runs of the same Outlook session

```
Sub test()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object

    Static count As Integer '<-- 'Static' preserves values between consecutive runs

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Check file open or not, and open it if it isn't opened
    If IsWorkBookOpen("D:\Book1.xlsx") Then
        Set xlWB = xlApp.workbooks("Book1.xlsx") '<-- 'workbooks()' acctepts only file name and extension
    Else
        Set xlWB = xlApp.workbooks.Open("D:\Book1.xlsx")
    End If

    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If count = 0 Then count = 2 '<-- 1st time it sets count to 2
    xlSheet.Cells(count, 1) = 1
    count = count + 1 '<-- increment count for next time to be left as it is before writing to xlSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bruce, did you get through it?

Comment: @Bruce, it'd be nice of you giving feedbacks to people trying at helping you. thank you