# How to remember value of public variable and use it when open excel file in the next time use VBA in outlook

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I would like to ask How can outlook remember value of public variable. I mean when I exit outlook, outlook still remember value of this variable and In the next time, when I open outlook again, It still remain value of this variable.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Excel?

Comment: @Bruce, it seems a follow up of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191712/set-default-public-variable-at-the-first-time-and-increase-it-in-the-next-time#40192228): proper feedback from you would help both you and people trying at helping you. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following has code to store information in the Registry (SaveMySettings) and retrieve this information (RetrieveMySettings).

The program saves two kevaluesys, "Item 1" and "Item 2" in this Registry key:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\My Program\Sub Program

```
Option Explicit

Const Reg_AppName As String = "My Program"
Const Reg_Section As String = "Sub Program"

Sub SaveMySettings()
  Dim Reg_Key As String
  Dim Reg_Value As String

  Reg_Key = "Item 1"
  Reg_Value = "First Value"
  SaveSetting Reg_AppName, Reg_Section, Reg_Key, Reg_Value

  Reg_Key = "Item 2"
  Reg_Value = "Second Value"
  SaveSetting Reg_AppName, Reg_Section, Reg_Key, Reg_Value
End Sub

Sub RetrieveMySettings()
  Dim Value1 As String, Value2 As String

  Value1 = GetSetting(Reg_AppName, Reg_Section, "Item 1")
  Value2 = GetSetting(Reg_AppName, Reg_Section, "Item 2")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Either persist the value of the variable to a file or to a place in the registry.

Comment: Could you please tell me more detail or give some reference document about that. It seem to be you mention SaveSetting and GetSetting Function which I have just searched

Comment: There are examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503174/how-to-create-and-write-to-a-txt-file-using-vba and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba